# Array with mixed contents not working. React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

Below is working fine for me:

```
{["msga ", <a href='url' target='_blank'>Click</a>," msgend."]}
```

But not below why(Means while assigning it to variable):

```
store.alertPopupContent = ["msga ", <a href='url' target='_blank'>Click</a>," msgend."];
{store.alertPopupContent}
```

Getting error, ***React is not defined***
Actually initially it was working for me.It started giving error from this time. React version:react@16.3.2

Comment: May be the quotes should be escaped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JSX code

`<a href='url' target='_blank'>Click</a>,`

[transpiles into](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html):

```
React.createElement(
  'a',
  { href: "url", target: "_blank" },
  "Click"
)
```

I bet you're not importing `react` in the place where your `store` is placed